# Concatenate in order by using decode in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, decode

I have below query in which I want to concatenate the combine column result of `FC,FM,MS` and sort based on color such that `'R'` should come first then `'Y'` and then `'G'`. I tried below query but the sorting doesn't work in proper order.

```
select bps.NAME as BNM, 
max(case when bbp.BID = 0.11 then os.SO end) FC,
max(case when bbp.BID = 0.12 then os.SO end) FM, 
max(case when bbp.BID = 0.13 then os.SO end) MS 
from PR_BP bbp
JOIN PR_BP_BPP bp ON bp.BP_ID = bbp.BP_ID
JOIN BRD b ON bbp.BID = b.BID
JOIN OS_VIEW os ON bbp.BP_ID = os.OD
where os.TO = 'PR_BP_BPP' AND bbp.B_A = 'Y'
group by bp.NAME
ORDER BY FC,FM,MS
```

Comment: Help us help you - Please share your tables structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve for this sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `CASE EXPRESSION` , I prefer it as it is easier to read:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN FC = 'R' THEN 1
              WHEN FC = 'Y' THEN 2
              WHEN FC = 'G' THEN 3
         END,
         CASE WHEN FM = 'R' THEN 1
              WHEN FM = 'Y' THEN 2
              WHEN FM = 'G' THEN 3
         END,
         CASE WHEN MS = 'R' THEN 1
              WHEN MS = 'Y' THEN 2
              WHEN MS = 'G' THEN 3
         END
```

That is if I understood what you want to do, I'm not I followed the logic you intended to do, I think what it does is checking when `FC||FM||MS` is equal to `R/Y/G` , which I believe is not

**EDIT:** If you want to order first by if one of them is 'R', then if one of the columns is 'Y' ...

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'R' IN(FC,FM,MS) THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END,
         CASE WHEN 'Y' IN(FC,FM,MS) THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END,
         CASE WHEN 'G' IN(FC,FM,MS) THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate your string concatenated values out into separate decodes:

```
ORDER BY DECODE( FC, 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 ),
         DECODE( FM, 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 ),
         DECODE( MS, 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 )
```

If you want to ignore values if they are `NULL` and just sort by the first non-`NULL` then:

```
ORDER BY DECODE( COALESCE( FC, FM, MS ), 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 ),
         DECODE( COALESCE( FM, MS),      'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 ),
         DECODE( MS,                     'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 )
```

or:

```
ORDER BY DECODE( COALESCE( FC, FM, MS ), 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 ),
         DECODE( COALESCE( FM, MS, FC ), 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 ),
         DECODE( COALESCE( MS, FC, FM ), 'R', 1, 'Y', 2, 'G', 3 )
```